# Vuetify - Breakpoints for columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've a simple Vue.js/Vuetify.js based SPA. The main page contains multiple cards arranged in a column layout. For now the card's width grows to the column's width. I want to use breakpoints like `xs10` or `sm8` for settings size responsive. However these breakpoints doesn't seem to work neither as attribute `xs10` nor as CSS class `class="xs10"`. The strange think is that they seems to work like a charm if I use a row layout instead... But I want just **one** card per row centered and **not** growing to full width...

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs10>
                <v-card color="red">
                    <v-card-title>Test</v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= webpackConfig.output.publicPath %>favicon.ico">
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but this app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
      <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I shrink the size of a flexbox/card in a column layout in a responsive way? Breakpoints doesn't seem to work properly...

**Edit**

The following image shows the problem, the card grows to layout/column width and ignores all breakpoints...

[image: Screendump]

Comment: just to clarify could you include a small picture of what you want to help clarify....[something like this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQQNaM?&editable=true&editors=101)?

Comment: Of course, I added a simple screen dump...

Comment: does setting the css work `.v-card{width: ###px;}`?

Comment: @depperm Sure this works there also exists an attribute called `max-width`, but than it doesn't resize in a responsive way...

Comment: @0x1C1B change column to `row wrap`. Why are you using a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use switch statements to control sizing on breakpoints.
Here is a Codepen link you can work with:  [Dynamic Sizing for Breakpoints](https://codepen.io/HarrisWebApps/pen/xvbVmG)

```
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
        <v-layout column align-center>
            <v-flex>
                <v-card color="red" :width='cardWidth'>
                    <v-card-title>{{ text }}</v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
             <v-flex>
                <v-card color="blue" :width='cardWidth'>
                    <v-card-title>{{ text }}</v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
             <v-flex>
                <v-card color="yellow" :width='cardWidth'>
                    <v-card-title>{{ text }}</v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'I want just one card per row centered and not growing to full width'
    }
  },
  computed: {
     cardWidth() {
            switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
                case "xs":
                    return "250px";
                case "sm":
                    return "350px";
                case "md":
                    return '600px';
                case "lg":
                    return '800px';
                case "xl":
                    return "1080px";
            }
        },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Vuetify API document, if you define `fluid` props in `v-container`, it will **remove viewport size breakpoints.**

So if you remove `fluid` props in `v-container`, viewport size breakpoints will going to work.

However, because `v-layout` has `column` props as true, any viewport size breakpoint will be ignored and each `v-flex` items becomes vertically aligned full sized items.

Instead of apply column props directly in `v-layout`, you can apply dynamic row or column breakpoints using computed property in script (but there may be easier way to apply this...).

Try [this code](https://codepen.io/chansbro/pen/ZgBLXe) in Codepen and see the differences: